# Filter invoke twice when register as Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I want to use `@Autowire` with a `Filter`. So I define my filter in the `SecurityConfig` as below:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(getA(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public A getA(){
        return new A();
    }
```

This filter `A` extends Spring's `GenericFilterBean`.

I get below output when I invoke the controller, which shows the filter hits twice.

```
filter A before
filter A before
mycontroller invoke
filter A after
filter A after
```

My observation is, this extra invocation invoke with Spring container because if filter is not register as bean, it only get hits once. What is the reason and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As you have observed, Spring Boot will automatically register any bean that is a `Filter` with the servlet container. One option is to not expose your `Filter` as a bean and only register it with Spring Security.

If you want to be able to autowire dependencies into your `Filter` then it has to be a bean. That means you need to tell Spring Boot not to register it as a `Filter`. As [described in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-disable-registration-of-a-servlet-or-filter), you do that using a `FilterRegistrationBean`:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean registration(MyFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registration.setEnabled(false);
    return registration;
}
```

Comment: One invocation is by the servlet container and the other is by Spring Security

Comment: There's no separate container for Spring Security, but it has its own chain of filters that are used to decide whether or not a request should be permitted.

Comment: It's not a double-registration. By explicitly providing a `FilterRegistrationBean` for the filter that is disabled, you're preventing Spring Boot from creating one that is enabled.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent Spring from creating a duplicate filter while also specifying the filter order? We would like to specify setOrder for a filter that's also a bean. The automatically registered filter is being placed near the end of our filter chain regardless of what we do with our FilterRegistrationBean.

Comment: @user1002065 And now how are you defining it? As @Bean?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Spring 6.0.2 or plus version and if using `OncePerRequestFilter`,
Overriding `shouldNotFilter` method as follows will work.

```
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getServletPath().contains("/api/path/which/needs/to/exclude");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Removing `@Component` from the filter class helped me.

```java
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

}
```