# Spring Security WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter Configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, pre-authentication

I have a simple Spring Boot application with the following 2 endpoints:

- int: requires Shibboleth SSO && Authorized Role
- ext: no SSO, no authorization required

I've implemented a `PreAuthenticationFilter` to work with SSO. Below is
the configuration that is not working:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/ext/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .and()
            .addFilter(preAuthenticationFilter());
    }
}
```

Shouldn't `PreAuthenticationFilter` bypass the `/ext` endpoint? However, the above configuration forces both endpoints to go to the `PreauthenticationFilter`. Also tried

```java
web.ignoring().antMatchers("/ext/**")
```

to no avail.

Here's the rest of my program:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/ext/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .and()
            .addFilter(preAuthenticationFilter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        //web.ignoring().antMatchers("/ext/**");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(new ShibbolethUserDetailsService());
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter preAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        ShibbolethRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter filter = new ShibbolethRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());       
        return filter;
    }
```

Comment: Yes.  Both Spring Boot & Thymeleaf are used.

Comment: *Shouldn't PreAuthenticationFilter bypass the /ext endpoint?* No, you added the filter, hence it is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter invoke twice when register as Spring bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314176/filter-invoke-twice-when-register-as-spring-bean)

Comment: You have to use the answer from the other question and also `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/ext/**")`.

Comment: @M-M: OP already wrote in his question, that `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/ext/**")` should work, so the question is IMO a duplicate. If OP would know the other question's answer, he had also tried `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/ext/**")` and it would work.

Comment: You are right.  Instead of making my custom PreAuthenticationFilter a Spring Bean, I ended up wiring it myself, and that fixed my problem. Thanks!