# How to completely ignore a certain path in spring http/web security

Tags: spring-security

I have a Spring Security configuration that works "authenticates" user by reading a specific header value. Thus using RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter():

```
private RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter requestHeaderFilter() throws Exception {
    RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
    authenticationFilter.setPrincipalRequestHeader("user");
    authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManager());
    return authenticationFilter;
}

private static final String HEALTH_PATH_NOAUTH = "/actuator/health";

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(HEALTH_PATH_NOAUTH);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.cors();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.addFilter(requestHeaderFilter());
}
```

I need to exclude a certain path from security: "/actuator/health"
First i tried to "permitAll" by configuring HttpSecurity:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HEALTH_PATH_NOAUTH).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
```

But neither this helped nor it helped to override "WebSecurity" as you see in the first listing.
RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter is always throwing it's exception if header is not set. I want this exception to be thrown, but not for this certain path.

How to solve this?

UPDATE: I removed the "bean" and made method private, but this should make no difference -  `web.ignoring().antMatchers(HEALTH_PATH_NOAUTH);` should work regardless of any filter add explicitly or as bean or even twice - right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter invoke twice when register as Spring bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314176/filter-invoke-twice-when-register-as-spring-bean)

Comment: in my case adding the filter is ok (twice also) - should "web.ignoring" not ignore all filters regardless how many?

Comment: No, it ignores only filters in the security filter chain. The second filter is in the web filter chain, which is not ignored.

Comment: what second filter?

Comment: The one which is added twice, first in the security filter chain and second in the servlet filter chain.