# How permit some specific path Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I know that already have a lot of questions equals... But nothing works and I am going to be crazy.

I have had implementing JWT authentication in a Spring project and my Security configurer is here:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        httpSecurity
            .headers().cacheControl();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/auth/**");
    }
```

But all path require token.... I am already try to use `@Secured("permitAll")` in my controller class but also doesn't work.

Comment: /auth/login -> 401 x(

Comment: yes.... the class is correct, i think that can be the pointer

Comment: In reallity maybe this filter that is before all calls?

Comment: Did you annotate `authenticationTokenFilterBean`with `@Bean`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter invoke twice when register as Spring bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314176/filter-invoke-twice-when-register-as-spring-bean)

Comment: why are you implementing a custom jwt filter when there is already one implemented in spring security that you can customize? read the docs

Comment: yeah, I change al the code to use spring security, now it's works. Thanks guys!